# When does onNewPicture() get called?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html) for onNewPicture() only says:

> Notify the listener that the picture
>   has changed

My question is: **When** does the picture change?

I noticed that some web pages generate dozens of onNewPicture(), so obviously the "picture" changes many times in the course of rendering the page on a WebView.

**What** makes a WebView picture change?

I haven't seen any page page that generates less than 2 onNewPicture() calls, so is onNewPicture() guaranteed to be called more than once, for any given HTML page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PictureListener.onNewPicture()` is called whenever the already loaded page finished rendering (or re-rendering in case certain events make the WebKit engine re-calculate page layout). It really depends on the page being loaded:

A simple text-only page will be rendered only once. Other pages (especially Javascript-heavy ones) can be called numerous times *after* the page finished loading.

Tip by @littleFluffyKitty found in [another posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065134/is-there-a-listener-for-when-the-webview-displays-its-content/4651507#4651507): Many webpages today will cause it to get called fairly often as you move around the page so make sure whatever happens in the `onNewPicture()` method is quick.